# How to rebase old commits (squashed in target) as empty?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-squash

We have a setup with two repositories, **dev** repository and **deploy** repository (can't change that) with rebase-only merge strategy. Initially **dev** repo looked like this:

```
   main: A -> B -> C -> D
        |______|  |______|
release:    Sq1 ->    Sq2
```

So `main` would have full linear history, and `release` contained squashed commits and will be rebased onto **deploy** repo's `main`. `release` also might have **deploy**-only commits, which would be rebased back from deploy, but will not be rebased onto main:

At some point squashing was removed, and only rebasing was done:

```
   main: A -> B -> C -> D -> E  -> F
        |______|  |______|
release:    Sq1 ->    Sq2 -> E* -> F*
```

So current situation:

```
[dev]
main: only dev commits
release: old squashed commits, new commits from main + some external commits not in main

[deploy]
main: almost like release in dev, but can contain some more external commits
```

Now, the problem is this: every time we rebase `main` onto `release` we need to manually skip all old `main` commits which were already merged but with squash. We don't want to be doing that.

My idea is to rebase them all into `release` but remove all changes - so that the git in the future will see that those commits were merged and will skip them automatically, leaving only new commits in the rebase. But I'm not sure how to do that. Also if there is a better way to solve this, I would be glad to hear that!

Comment: What about using `rerere` to remember skipping the commits?

Comment: @choroba I will have to test it out, but that does seem to be one approach, making the process easier. I wonder though if we can get rid of skips completely... Thanks for the suggestions, first time I see `rerere`, looks handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My idea is to rebase them all into `release` but remove all changes - so that the git in the future will see that those commits were merged and will skip them automatically, leaving only new commits in the rebase.

I doubt that would work: a commit is skipped during a rebase if the *same content* is detected, as [illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58917743/6309).

> Now, the problem is this: every time we rebase `main` onto `release`.

That is the issue right there: permanent branches (like main or releases) are not supposed to be rebased onto anywhere.
There can be merge *to* (from feature/dev branches to them).
You might consider merging `main` to `release`, to record a given release.

But no rebase should be done with those branches. You can rebase a feature/dev branch on top of main, when you plan to make a pull request.

Comment: Thanks for clarification! Yeah, we ended up ditching release branch and making deploy repo be a complete mirror of our dev repo (the two repo system is needed for client's internal use and certifications). Now no need to rebase main onto anything.

Comment: @Virgileo Well done, yes, that is the way!